# PHP parse query string to associative array

Tags: php

When we make GET request using query string like this:

```
answers[0][answer]=ABC2&answers[0][id]=1&answers[1][answer]=XYZ&answers[1][id]=2&answers[2][answer]=QWE&answers[2][id]=3
```

PHP parses this string to an associative like following

```
Array
(
    [answers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [answer] => ABC2
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [answer] => XYZ
                    [id] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [answer] => QWE
                    [id] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

How can I do the same manually with a string stored in a variable?

Comment: Have you tried [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) / [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) or [json-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) / [json-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) could be options as well depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman)

`parse_str()` worked as I wanted. However `parse_str()` does not return the parsed variables. It just creates the variable in current scope.